# Ajax call not accepting function parameter as data value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass the value stored in the function argument to the PHP page using data, however Ajax always executes the error section generating the popup - alert.

The code is attached below. Any suggestions. thanks in advance

```
function clickonaccept(contentid)
{

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../scripts/s_updateinvites.php',
        data: { id: contentid},
        error: function() 
        {
           alert('Error!');
        },
        success: function(data) 
        {
           alert ('updatedt!');
        }
    });
}
```

**contents of script s_updateinvites.php**

```
<?PHP

    include_once ("s_dbconnect.php");
    $connectobject= new dbconnect();

    $con = $_POST["id"]; 

    $connectobject->query("INSERT INTO workingon (Content_ID) VALUES ('$con')");

?>
```

Comment: can you check the browser console for any errors

Comment: Could be that the path to your script is wrong....

Comment: are you getting value of `contentid` in the function?? have you checke din console??

Comment: Hey Guys, i checked the path of the script. this is correct. just to ensure that the function argument is actually receiving the value, i have checked by adding an alert function alert(contentid), when the function is called, the alert pop up reflects the correct value. It is only post that the error from ajax occurs.

Comment: Hi Arun, I used the browser console in firefox and got these repsones in the log when this function is called   --
[19:43:19.557] GET http://localhost/development/pages/p_invite.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1031ms]                                [19:43:20.531] NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aborted by user @ resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js:425

Comment: Hi can go with this link http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ try to track down the error with this.

Comment: @RajatModi , hey rajat! thanks. tried the error message thing. it says error requesting page ../scripts/s_updateinvites.php  seems strange as the pages are all located in correct places

Comment: @ArunPJohny - any other suggestions!

Comment: @user2131970 what is the returned value? is it html, json etc

Comment: @ArunPJohny the php file only updates records in the database and does not return any value. the idea is to pass the contentid to the script. the PHP script then looks up the id in the database and only changes its value from disabled to active. no value is returned.

Comment: can try adding `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax settings

Comment: @arun dusnt work with dataType also. do u thnk there is some syntax error or a missing statement

Comment: @ArunPJohny is there any function / script that will throw back the exact error?

Comment: also post s_updateinvites.php code here and try with static url.

Comment: and what is the exception you may also get with global ajaxerror function the link which I posted earlier..

Comment: @RajatModi. Hi, i guess the php contents are not displaying properly above. the php script is quite simpe about 4 lines. i am attaching the same here as well   <?PHP
    
    include_once ("s_dbconnect.php");
    $connectobject= new dbconnect();
    
    $con = $_POST["id"]; 
    
    $connectobject->query("INSERT INTO workingon (Content_ID) VALUES ('$con')");

?>

Comment: i am not a pro so i used the example on the jquery error page which is $(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
  $( "#msg" ).append( "<li>Error requesting page " + settings.url + "</li>" );
}); and got the error as error requesting page ../scripts/s_updateinvites.php

Answer (score 0):

use this code and let me know if you have any problem.

```
function clickonaccept(contentid)
{
  // I hope you are getting content
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/YOUR_PROJECT/scripts/s_updateinvites.php',//preferable is if you already define site path. not ../ path
    data: { id: contentid},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
      if(data.message=="done")
      {
        alert("yes Cracked!!!");
      }
    }
});
//I removeed error code from your code and used datatype json
}
```

Now I changed below in your code.

```
include_once ("s_dbconnect.php");
$connectobject= new dbconnect();

$con = $_POST["id"]; 

$connectobject->query("INSERT INTO workingon (Content_ID) VALUES ('$con')");

$data = array("message"=>"done")
echo json_encode($data);
die;
```

Comment: ..hey thanks for the script..but it din't work :(. the data in the contentid variable shows if i insert an alert(contentid) but as soon as ajax sets in it doesn't work.

Comment: strange :) now alert(contentid) and just before it write  return false and see alert is coming or not? then remove return false and does it show success alert?

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Can't figure out still whats the difference

function check()
{

```
var value=2;
alert(value);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 's_updateinvites.php',
    data: { id: value },
    cache: false,
    error: function() 
    {
       alert('Error!');
    },
    success: function(data) 
    {
        alert ('Done!');
    }
});
```

}

"update"

and the PHP file is

include_once ("s_dbconnect.php");
    $connectobject = new dbconnect();

```
$check = $_POST["id"];
$connectobject->query("INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('$check')");
```